# How to encode post content as JSON?

Tags: the-content, encoding, json

I`m trying to construct a json object but are having difficulties with the_content since it returns newlines, which causes the script to fail. The error messages received is: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

**Example of the json:**

```
[ {image : 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/example.png', title: 'Example string

with newlines
that outputs illegally!'}]
```

Ideally I'd want it to output the HTML content (as seen when pressing the HTML tab in the editor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output JSON always the function [`json_encode( $string )`](http://php.net/json-encode). The function is not available on all hosts. Don't worry, WordPress offers a fallback in `wp-includes/compat.php`. That's a wrapper for `class Services_JSON::encodeUnsafe()` (see `wp-includes/class-json.php`).
If you take a look at the source you'll see: It's not a trivial job to encode a string. :)

There is a small difference: The native PHP `json_encode()` accepts a second parameter `$options` since PHP 5.3.0. The WordPress fallback doesn't.

New lines are encoded as `'\n'` in JSON; you cannot get the same output as in the HTML tab in TinyMCE.

And there is, of course, also a fallback for `json_decode()` in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a wp function : wp_json_encode() that can do the job
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/