# Widget with random posts from a blog for external sites

Tags: widgets, endpoints

How can I create a customizable widget with random posts from my blog that can be published on another site as js, iframe or div.
Is there any Wordpress plugin for that?

Answer (score 6):

To create a special output of random posts:

1. [Register an endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to the root of your blog. See [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to the WordPress Rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) for details.
2. Refresh the permalink settings. I would do this on (de)activation only.
3. Hook into `'template_redirect'` and return your output depending on the details of the requested endpoint. Then `exit`.

That’s all.

Well … some code may help to understand the details. :)

Let’s build a small plugin for HTML and JSON output.

I have named it **T5 Random Posts Endpoint**; all code goes into a class with static methods to keep the global namespace clean.

```
add_action( 'init', array ( 'T5_Random_Posts_Endpoint', 'init' ) );

/**
 * Build a root endpoint.
 */
class T5_Random_Posts_Endpoint
{
    /**
     * Register endpoint and actions.
     *
     * @wp-hook 'init'
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        add_rewrite_endpoint( 'randomposts', EP_ROOT );
        add_filter( 'request', array ( __CLASS__, 'filter_request' ) );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array ( __CLASS__, 'render' ) );
    }
}
```

As you can see, we call a central `init` method on `'init'` to … initialize our plugin. Creative naming, huh?

The endpoint is named `randomposts` and attached to the root. So after activation you can get the out put on `example.com/randomposts/` or `example.com/randomposts/json/`.

But … if you call the first URL the endpoint works and the request variable `randomposts` is set – but it is **empty**. That’s why we hook into `'request'` and give the variable a **default value** we can work with later. Let’s use `html` as default:

```
    /**
     * Prepare the endpoint variable so it has always a value.
     *
     * @wp-hook 'request'
     * @param   array $request
     * @return  array
     */
    public static function filter_request( $request )
    {
        if ( isset ( $request['randomposts'] )
            and empty ( $request['randomposts'] )
        )
        {
            $request['randomposts'] = 'html';
        }

        return $request;
    }
```

Now we hook into `'template_redirect'` so WordPress will not use the default template `index.php` but our own output.

```
    /**
     * Create output.
     *
     * @wp-hook 'template_redirect'
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function render()
    {
        // This is not our endpoint.
        if ( '' === $type = get_query_var( 'randomposts' ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        // Someone is poking around.
        // You can extend this and build different output variants.
        if ( ! in_array( $type, array ( 'html', 'json' ) ) )
        {
            status_header( 414 );
            print 'Unsupported Media Type. Use "html" or "json" only.';
            exit;
        }

        // Empty blog?
        if ( ! $posts = get_posts( array ( 'numberposts' => 10, 'orderby' => 'rand' ) ) )
        {
            status_header( 404 );
            print 'No posts found.';
            exit;
        }

        self::$type( self::prepare_post_data( $posts ) );
        exit;
    }
```

First we check if we are really on our endpoint by looking into `get_query_var( 'randomposts' )`. We filled this variable in our request filter, so if it is *still* empty, we know *for sure* that is not our business and we return quickly.

Then we test if the request was for one of our predefined output variants `html` or `json`. If someone is calling `/randomposts/css` or `/randomposts/lala` we raise a 414 error with a helpful message. And exit.

Then we get finally our posts with [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Random_posts) and remove all the data we don’t need in a dedicated method named `prepare_post_data()`:

```
    /**
     * Build a simple array with just titles and permalinks.
     *
     * @wp-hook 'template_redirect'
     * @param   array $posts
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function prepare_post_data( $posts )
    {
        $data = array ();

        foreach ( $posts as $post )
        {
            if ( empty ( $post->post_title) )
            {
                continue;
            }

            $data[ $post->ID ] = array (
                'title' => strip_tags( $post->post_title ),
                'url'   => get_permalink( $post->ID )
            );
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

We pass this simple array to a method named exactly like our output: `html()` or `json()`.
Let’s start with `json()`; that’s the easy part. See [How to encode post content as JSON?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51500/how-to-encode-post-content-as-json/51522#51522) for some background.

```
    /**
     * Render JSON output
     *
     * @wp-hook 'template_redirect'
     * @param  array $data
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function json( array $data )
    {
        header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
        print json_encode( $data );
    }
```

Easy, isn’t it? The `html()` is not that much harder, just longer:

```
        /**
         * Render HTML output
         *
         * @wp-hook 'template_redirect'
         * @param  array $data
         * @return void
         */
        protected static function html( array $data )
        {
            ?>
<!doctype html>
<title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<?php
// Just a sample style. Be creative! :)
?>
<style>
body, body *
{
    display:         block;
    font:            1em/1.4 Calibri, sans-serif;
    list-style:      none;
    margin:          0;
    padding:         0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a
{
    background:      #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom:   1px solid #ddd;
    color:           #333;
    padding:         5px 10px;
}
a:hover, a:focus
{
    background:      #333;
    color:           #f5f5f5;
}
h1 a
{
    font-size:      1.2em;
    font-weight:    bold;
}
</style>
<h1><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ( $data as $post )
{
    print '<li><a href="' . $post['url'] . '">' . $post['title'] . '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
        }
```

This is how it looks with the [theme test data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test):

[image]

Now our output is finished – we are still in `render()` – and we call `exit` because otherwise WordPress would include the `index.php` from the active theme.

Now we need just a method to refresh the permalink settings:

```
    /**
     * Reset permalinks.
     *
     * @wp-hook 'activate_' . __FILE__
     * @wp-hook 'deactivate_' . __FILE__
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function flush_rewrite_rules()
    {
        remove_action( 'init', array ( __CLASS__, 'init' ) );
        add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules', 11 );
    }
```

We prevent our default `init` hook here because on activation we are on the plugin list where we don’t need the endpoint, and on deactivation we do not want to re-register the now unused permalink.

We attach this method to (de)activation with:

```
// refresh permalink settings
register_activation_hook(
    __FILE__ ,
    array ( 'T5_Random_Posts_Endpoint', 'flush_rewrite_rules' )
);
register_deactivation_hook(
    __FILE__ ,
    array ( 'T5_Random_Posts_Endpoint', 'flush_rewrite_rules' )
);
```

And now we can say: That’s all. Really.

If you made it this far grab the **[complete plugin from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/3033771)**.

Answer (score 0):

I think in essence what you're talking about is a Custom Widget that will parse and display RSS Feed of your Blog. Here, you can build a Custom Widget of your own and hard-code the RSS Feed URL of your Blog in your Widget PHP itself to make sure Widget User doesn't change the URL; so your widget will show RSS of your Blog only.

Now, once you finalize to use RSS to fork your Blog, you've several options open in front of you. Either you can use Wordpress's own RSS Feed abilities to save you time (but this will impose many limitations) OR write your own RSS Feed maker code as Web Service installed on your Server/Web Hosting that will interact with your Widget. So, make your Widget PHP to send request to your Blog's RSS Feed Publishing Web Service; then parse the results returned by your Server and display RSS Feed items.

If you've time to invest and serious about this Widget, then better you implement your own Web Service. I don't think it'll be too hard for you... just play with WP_Query and return the results in proper RSS Feed XML Format. This way you will also be able to offer Category list in Drop-down to your Widget User to choose from and make your Widget PHP to request RSS of Posts only from selected Category of your Blog. Plus, you'll have better control over how many Posts to return in RSS Feed requested by your Widget.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,

Ruturaaj.

Comment: Ok, forget about that Web Service part... I think that made the answer look too difficult to implement. See if one of these plugins give you a quick start:

RSS Import:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/

Use this plugin in your Widget. All hard-work of reading and parsing RSS is already done.

Simple RSS Feed Widget:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-rss-feeds-widget/

You may study this widget. The goal is to remove the Text-area of the Widget where it takes Feed URLs and replace it with your own hard-coded URL.

Hope this simplifies the solution. :-)

Ruturaaj.

Comment: Using Simple Rss Feeds Widgets it's a matter of: 
1) putting only your feed to be displayed. 
2) setting the maximum from the same source to, say, 60 items. 
3) changing the line of code `usort( $displayedItems, 'SimpleRssFeedsWidget_Widget::sort' );` to `shuffle( $displayedItems );`