# Output JSON and no theme

Tags: json

I would like my plugin to create a url which only outputs JSON.

The JSON feed contains settings and other info about this plugin.

I would like to know how my plugin registers a url which only outputs JSON data using Wordpress function.

For example: the user goes to example.com/pluginfeed
This is a JSON Feed containing posts, settings and more

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Just added some info to the question

Comment: you want the user to be logged in to access that url?

Comment: No thats not necessary. The problem i am facing is that i cant echo json data without the theme, sidebars and default wordpress

Comment: I suppose you have done your research and have seen: [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57155/22534) and/or [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9870/22534).

Comment: Yes i have seen those posts but i cant seem to figure out how to echo only JSON, when i create an Wordpress end point i am getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Comment: have you considered extending the json rest API plugin thats slated to be bundled into Core soon?